# JavaScript & Default Values on a Prototype

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript. I've done quite a bit of Google searching, but have not been able to find the answer I seek -- likely because I am using the wrong terminology.

The other day, I was reading a basic tutorial about creating JavaScript components: http://callmenick.com/post/javascript-objects-building-javascript-component-part-2

Part of the tutorial involves a set of default options, which are assigned to a type's prototype chain:

```
SimpleAlert.prototype.options = {
  wrapper : document.body,
  type : "default",
  message : "Default message."
}
```

The idea being that the `SimpleAlert` type can be created with different parameters if the user provides them during construction - otherwise the default options are used.

The `SimpleAlert` constructor function looks like this:

```
function SimpleAlert( options ) {
this.options = extend( {}, this.options ); // Why?
extend( this.options, options );
// start the functionality...
}
```

And the `extend` function is defined as:

```
function extend( a, b ) {
for( var key in b ) { 
  if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
    a[key] = b[key];
  }
}
return a;
}
```

My understanding of this code is:

Creating a new `SimpleAlert` object involves the user passing in their own `options` object. Let's say I pass in `{ test : "Testing" }` for the `options` parameter.  The `extend` function then accesses `this.options` (which I believe refers to the prototype's instance of `options` since there is no other `options` variable defined in the scope) and essentially copies everything from the shared instance to the empty `{}` object, which is then assigned to the shared `this.options` instance.

Then, the user supplied `options` (in my case `{ test : "Testing" }` is `extend`ed int the `this.options` shared instance (basically copying my extra `test` field into the shared instance)

But in reality, it seems that the shared instance is not affected in this example -- meaning the `SimpleAlert.prototype.options` declaration remains unchanged so that each new instance of `SimpleAlert` has access to it (which is what I want)

However, in my experimentation, I find that changing `this.options` results in the prototype value being modified... I'm sure whatever I'm doing wrong is simple to fix, but I cannot see it.  Here is an example:

```
    var Animal = function(ovr) {
        if (arguments.length > 0)
        {
        this.options.mode = ovr;
        }

    };

    Animal.prototype.options = { mode: "Test" }; / I want this to be default for all instances created

    var test = new Animal("Override"); // set this test obj to use "Overide"
    console.log(test.options.mode); // outputs Override as expected
    var again = new Animal();
    console.log(again.options.mode); // also outputs Override (I want it to say "Test")
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already suggested in your code, it's missing the "copy" operation so you're modifying the shared object on the prototype.

```
var Animal = function(ovr) {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        // Copy whatever is on this.options to a blank object,
        // then assign this.options to be that newly copied object, so
        // the prototype object is masked by the instance object.
        this.options = Object.assign({}, this.options);
        this.options.mode = ovr;
    }
};
```

This might help to understand how the instance property "masks" the prototype:

```
var Foo = function() {
    console.log('a', this.x);
    this.x = 100;
    console.log('b', this.x);
    delete this.x;
    console.log('c', this.x);
};

Foo.prototype.x = 1;

new Foo();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still not understanding something.  this.options is the shared instance on the prototype, right? So Object.assign({}, this.options} copies the shared instance to an empty object...but then that object (now filled) is reassigned back to this.options...which is the shared instance, right?

Comment: No, it's not. In simple terms, when you ask for "this.options", it looks on the instance first for an options property. If that doesn't exist, then it looks up the prototype chain. So the instance option "masks" the prototype. Updated answer.

Comment: Oh, okay so the assignment of `this.x` in the `Foo` constructor function is implicitly creating a variable that shadows the prototype's variable?  Curiously, I notice if I change `this.x = 100;` to `var x = 100`, it doesn't seem to shadow?

Comment: Because `var` is a local function variable, not an instance variable.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the excellent explanation and example.